# this.props.dispatch().then is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am trying to do something as soon as a `dispatch` action finishes, and a similar question led me to try to use `.then`. I get an error that it doesn't exist, `this.props.dispatch().then is not a function`:

```
export function unpackStore(redux_store, namespace) {
    // namespace is determined by what name you gave each reducer in combineReducers; client/reducers/index.js
    let final_props = {};
    let KEYS = Object.keys(redux_store[namespace]);
    for (let key of KEYS) {
        final_props[key] = redux_store[namespace][key];
    }
    return final_props;
}

export function basicUnpackStoreClosure(namespace) {
    return function(store) {
        let props = unpackStore(store, namespace);
        return props;
    }
}



@connect(basicUnpackStoreClosure('login_info'))
export default class LoginPage extends MyComponent {

    constructor(props) {
        let custom_methods = [
            'handleLoginOrRegisterToggle',
            'handleOnKeyDownInInputs',
            'onLoginSubmit',
            'onRegisterSubmit',
        ]
        super(props, custom_methods);
        this.state = {
            mode: 'login',
            email: '',
            password: '',
            password_confirm: ''
        };
        if (props.mode == 'register') {
            this.state.mode = 'register';
        }

    }

    onLoginSubmit() {

        let self = this;

        let reroute = function() {
            browserHistory.push(self.props.destination_url);
        }

        this.props.dispatch({type: 'LOG_IN', payload: "fake@fake.com"})
          .then((response) => {
              browserHistory.push(self.props.destination_url);
          })
    }
```

We also tried the way you do something when `this.setState` finishes, passing it as a second arg:

```
this.props.dispatch({type: 'LOG_IN', payload: "fake@fake.com"}, reroute)
```

neither worked. The `this.props.dispatch` seems to come for free with using the `@connect` decorator. How can I run something only after this Redux store is updated with the "LOG_IN" action?

Comment: So, your question is, how to get `Promise` from the dispatch call, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally the connect HOC is used to bind the actions with a component. For an example,

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ApplicationContainer);
```

After you do this, `then this.props.getApplications` will be bound where `getApplications` is the action you need to fire.

As per your comment, if you want to have access to `this.props.dispatch` INSTEAD of binding actions, simply call `connect()` without passing any mappers, and the default behavior will inject dispatch.

Comment: I'm not sure if that will help; `dispatch` is injected, it's there...but we can't call `.then(...)` on it, which was the suggestion I saw.

We want to run a callback AFTER the dispatch finishes it's job, meaning after the redux store is updated

Comment: Please help me sir, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67180197/how-to-pass-props-data-from-render-to-handlesubmit-function-in-redux

Answer (score 0):

You may install 'redux-promise' middleware and include it in your store. The problem here is that the promise is not getting fulfilled. Including 'redux-promise' middleware will solve the problem